# Marginal likelihood of implicit model

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function, likelihood, marginal-distribution

In the introduction of ["Implicit Maximum Likelihood Estimation" (Li et al., 2018)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.09087), **implicit models** are defined as the deterministic parameterized transformation $T_\theta(\cdot)$ of an analytic distribution e.g. an isotropic Gaussian:

1. Sample $\mathbf{z} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathbf{I})$
2. Return $\mathbf{x} := T_\theta(\mathbf{z})$

The marginal likelihood of such models is written as:

\begin{equation}
p_{\theta}(\mathbf{x}) =\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}} \cdots \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{d}} \int_{\left\{\mathbf{z} | \forall i\left(T_{\theta}(\mathbf{z})\right)_{i} \leq x_{i}\right\}} \phi(\mathbf{z}) d \mathbf{z} \\  
\end{equation}

where $\phi(\cdot)$ denotes the probability density function (PDF) of $\mathcal{N}(0, \mathbf{I})$.

---

Why is this the case?

It seems like the integral $\int_{\left\{\mathbf{z} | \forall i\left(T_{\theta}(\mathbf{z})\right)_{i} \leq x_{i}\right\}} \phi(\mathbf{z}) d \mathbf{z}$ is the CDF evaluated at $\mathbf{z}$, since generally speaking the CDF is the integral of the PDF from $-\inf$ to $\mathbf{z}$, i.e. $F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(x)\mathrm dx$.

Why would the chained partial derivatives of the CDF of the latent variable $\mathbf{z}$ (is it in a sense w.r.t. $T_\theta$?) yield the marginal likelihood of the transformed $\mathbf{z}$?

Might be on the completely wrong track here. Would appreciate some enlightenment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p_\theta(\bf x)$ is the constructed likelihood function(intractable model density) and not marginal likelihood. The chain of partial derivatives indicates that the auxiliary function(CDF) used is differentiable in all dimensions. ["Learning in Implicit Generative Models" (Mohamed and Lakshminarayanan, 2016)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.03483.pdf) is a good reference concerning the learning and other notations involved.
Hope this helps!

---

From Mohamed and Lakshminarayanan (2016):

[image: Notation and definition]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Just for posterity, [a reference for how transformed Y := f(X) is the derivative of the CDF](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Probability_Densities#math_8). I also edited your answer to include a screenshot :)

Comment: Thanks and welcome:)